# Issue with navigation in React Native between TabNavigator and StackNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

for a few days I've been stumbling over a problem and I can't find the solution... In my application I have a tabNavigator and a stackNavigator.

My problem is that in my tabNavigator I want to put an icon in my headerRight and when you click on it you go to the stack corresponding to my shopping cart. When I enter the name of my stack in the navigator, which is "Cart", I get an error: `The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name": "Cart"} was not handled by any navigator. Do you have a screen named 'Cart'?`

I can only navigate to a tab.Screen when I need to navigate to my Stack.

Their is my TabNavigator :

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TabNavigator = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={() => ({
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: appColors.primary,
          height: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 60 : undefined,
        },
        headerTitle: () => <Logo />,
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerRight: () => (
          <Feather
            name="shopping-cart"
            size={24}
            color="white"
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate("Cart");
            }}
          />
        ),
        headerRightContainerStyle: {
          paddingEnd: 10,
        },
      })}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="News"
        component={HomePageStack}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
            <Entypo name="news" size={40} color="black" />
          ),
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Cheval"
        component={HorseStack}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="horse" size={40} color="black" />
          ),
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Sell"
        component={SellStack}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
            <Entypo name="shopping-basket" size={40} color="black" />
          ),
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default TabNavigator;
```

And my StackNavigator :

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

const MainStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="HomePage"
        component={HomePageStack}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

// Stack for the news
const HomePageStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="DetailsNewsScreen"
        component={DetailsNewsScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const HorseStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Horse"
        component={HorseScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const SellStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SellStack"
        component={HomeSellScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ServicesSell"
        component={ServicesScreen}
        options={{
          title: "",
          headerBackTitle: "Retour",
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ClothesScreen"
        component={ClothesScreen}
        options={{
          title: "",
          headerBackTitle: "Retour",
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="HorseActivity"
        component={HorseActivityScreen}
        options={{
          title: "",
          headerBackTitle: "Retour",
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const LoginStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Login"
        component={LoginScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const CartStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Cart"
        component={HomeScreenCart}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export {
  MainStackNavigator,
  HomePageStack,
  HorseStack,
  SellStack,
  LoginStack,
  CartStack,
};
```

I tried to use the props of the screenOptions it doesn't works. I also tried to use the navigation with useNavigation and same it doesn't work.

Comment: `tried to use the props of the screenOptions it` Can you add a few more details about what you tried and what the result was?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson I tried this code with the screenOptions : 
```js
screenOptions={({ navigation }) => ({ })}
```

And I got this error : ```The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Cart"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'Cart'?```

The problem is that it can't navigate outside of the tabNavigator when I click in the headerRight and I want to navigate to my Stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `TabNavigator` is the root stack, it is unaware of the existence of the `CartStack` since it is not used as a screen in the `TabNavigator` or any of it's children.

If the `CartStack` is not intended to be a child screen of the `TabNavigator`, then you will need a parent navigator to contain both stacks.

```
export function AppNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="MainTabs">
      <Stack.Screen name="MainTabs" component={TabNavigator} />
      <Stack.Screen name="CartStack" component={CartStack} />
      // ... other root level navigation stacks
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

This will allow you to navigate to the `Cart` screen from anywhere with:

```
navigation.navigate("CartStack", {screen: "Cart"})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it finally works with your solution . You save me a lot of time.

Comment: Terrific! Glad I could help! Do you mind marking this as the solution and giving it an upvote?